# Android Tabs with TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create an Application with tabs, and I have found this guide http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html on the Internet, I have choosen to follow.

I have created an XML-file for the Layout, that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dip">
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="5dp">
      <TableLayout android:id="@+id/aTableLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I also created a class to create the Tabs due to the guide, which is shown below.

```
public class GuiTabs extends TabActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabslayout);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, GuiRegistration.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Reg").setIndicator("Registration").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("Reg");
  }
}
```

Now I need to generate the content of the tabs, where one of the tabs is GuiRegistration.
I have designed the GuiRegistration in a XML-file, but I also need to add actions to buttons e.g., so I have to use the GuiRegistration-class. 
But how can I create the tab, because I have tried using

```
setContentView(R.layout.registration)
```

Design the tab directy in the class

And

```
public class GuiRegistration extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View aTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.aTableLayout);
    ViewGroup vGroup = (ViewGroup) aTabLayout.getParent();
    int index = vGroup.indexOfChild(aTabLayout);
    vGroup.removeViewAt(index);
    View newTabLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.registration, vGroup, false);
    vGroup.addView(newTabLayout, index);
  }
}
```

But nothing seems to work, can somebody tell me how to make it work?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please be more specific

Comment: i think you need tabhost too .

Comment: I have edited the question now, so I hope that make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code, your Guiregistration class is not calling
setContentView(R.layout.registration)

May be thats why the  view is not drawn in the tab.

Comment: It was not the answer, but as I found another solution, I accept you answer as the correct answer